# Find $f(x)$ from recurrence and sum notation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ be real ($\mathbb{R}$) *non-zero* constants such that $\overset n{\underset {k=1}\sum} a_k \in \mathbb{R}$. Find $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, *differentiable* in $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\overset n{\underset{k=1}\sum}f(x+a_ky)=nf(x)+by$$where $x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}$\ {$0$}.

I have no idea what to try and do in order to solve it....

Comment: Write it as $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f(x+a_ky)-f(x)}{y}=b$. Take limits as $y\to0$ You get that $nf'(x)=b$. Therefore, $f'(x)=b/n$ for all $x$. This means that $f(x)=bx/n+C$ for certain constant $C$. Putting this in the original equation you get that $bx+nC+y\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=bx+nC+by$. Therefore, there is a solution iff $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=b$, and the solution is $f(x)=bx/n+C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: @deyore Really nice sir, I did it, Thank you! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can write it with all details to make sure that you understood.

Comment: @deyore When you take the limit and you use L'hospital with respect to $y$ then should't you get $f'(a_k)=b$?

Comment: You don't use L'Hospital. You use the definition of derivative. There is actually an error above $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+a_ky)}{y}=a_k\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+a_ky)}{a_ky}=a_kf'(x)$. There is an $a_k$ missing in front. It should be $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kf'(x)=b$. Therefore, $f'(x)=b/\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$.

Comment: Actually L'Hospital cannot be used, since you end up having to take the limit of $a_kf'(x+a_ky)$ when $y\to0$. But we don't know if $f'$ is continuous. We only know that the derivative exists.

Comment: @deyore Yeah, I just uploaded an answer, correct me if I'm wrong somewhere please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I understood  from @deyoree is this:

We have:

$$\overset n{\underset{k=1}\sum}f(x+a_ky)=nf(x)+by$$
$$\overset n{\underset{k=1}\sum}[f(x+a_ky)-f(x)]=by$$
$$\frac{\overset n{\underset{k=1}\sum}[f(x+a_ky)-f(x)]}{y}=b$$

And now, if we take the $\lim_{y\to0}$ of this expression

We get:

$$\overset n{\underset{k=1}\sum}a_kf'(x)=b$$
<=>$$f'(x) = \frac {b}{\overset n{\underset{k=1}\sum}a_k}$$

If we integrate:

$$f(x) = \frac {b}{\overset n{\underset{k=1}\sum}a_k}x+c$$

And this is enough for my problem and I'll leave the answer as it is.

Comment: Looks good. But the final part is important. Taking limit is not an equivalent transformation. Therefore, the answer at the end could contain false solutions. You do need to check which of those are valid solutions by putting them in the original equation. Maybe an extra condition for $b,a_k,c$ arises.

Answer (score 0):

Try $f(x)=x$ and $b=\overset n{\underset {k=1}\sum} a_k \in \mathbb{R}$